# How can we verify response data (column values) in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have an assertion that confirms the existence of data in the table, how to make the assertion confirm the presence of metadata (column names)

my assertion
`int num_vars = vars.get("rs_uc08_#") as Integer; if(num_vars==0){ AssertionResult.setFailure(true); }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the column names as they're displayed in the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

[image]

you can access them as the first line of the response using `prev.getResponseDataAsString()` function where `prev` stands for **prev**ious [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)

Example code:

```
prev.getResponseDataAsString().split('\\n')[0].split('\\t').eachWithIndex { column, index ->
    log.info('Column ' + (index + 1) + ': ' + column)
}
```

and demo:

[image]

I cannot tell you how exactly you need to assert the values as I don't know in what form do you have the expected columns names list. Check out [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) guide for more information if needed.